# Loading Esri ArcGrid export file (e00) in R?

Tags: raster, r, linux, e00, red-hat

I am trying to load an ESRI ArcGrid export file into R. The file is located at- ftp://ftp.epa.gov/castnet/tdep/grids/n_tw/n_tw-2013.zip. The documentation for this file states, "Gridded data of the above variables are available in compressed ESRI ArcGRID export files" and not much else. Link to documentation  [here](ftp://ftp.epa.gov/castnet/tdep/Total_Deposition_Documentation_current.pdf). My major problem is that this is an `e00` file, an old output format of Arc.

The most straightforward way to load a raster normally (if this wasn't an `e00` file) would be:

```
require(raster)
require(rgdal)    
test <- raster('/path/to/n_tw-2013.e00')
```

However, you will receive the error: `n_tw-2013.e00 not recognised as a supported file format.`.

The `RArcInfo` package claims to be able to convert `.e00` files into more useful Arc/Info binary coverage. To do this:

```
require(RArcInfo)
#first argument is the path to the e00 file, and the second argument is the new directory to create
e00toavc('/path/to/n_tw-2013.e00','/path/to/test1')
```

When I run this command it prints `NULL`, and creates two directories, `test1`, and `info`, however, both are empty. I'm not sure whats going wrong here.

How do I get this loaded into R as a raster so I can extract data to my specific lat/long?

Output of `sessionInfo` pasted here:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS release 6.7 (Final)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] rgdal_1.2-5  raster_2.5-8 sp_1.2-4    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.2     Rcpp_0.12.3     grid_3.2.2      lattice_0.20-33
```

Comment: It appears you are dealing with an Arc Exchange file - check this out [How To: Import an ArcInfo interchange file (E00) in ArcGIS](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000004705). Your trying to do this using R

Comment: see [RArchInfo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RArcInfo/index.html) package  for reading`.e00` files in r

Comment: @ImranAli see updated question. The `RArcInfo` package still is not solving my problem for some reason.

Comment: I can read it using `raster()`. Maybe update the packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no problem reading in the file using `rgdal 1.2-3` and `raster 2.5-8`:

```
require(raster)
require(rgdal)   
test <- raster('n_tw-2013.e00')
test
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 775, 1440, 1116000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 4134.354, 4134.354  (x, y)
extent      : -2950369, 3003101, 115686.8, 3319811  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=aea +lat_1=0 +lat_2=29.5 +lat_0=45.5 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=-96 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
data source : /Users/Martin/Desktop/n_tw-2013.e00 
names       : n_tw.2013 
values      : 0.8068619, 70.83445  (min, max)
```

---

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.12.2 (Sierra)

locale:
[1] de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/C/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] raster_2.5-8 sp_1.2-3    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.7       plotly_4.5.2      magrittr_1.5      munsell_0.4.3     colorspace_1.2-7 
 [6] viridisLite_0.1.3 lattice_0.20-34   R6_2.2.0          httr_1.2.1        plyr_1.8.4       
[11] dplyr_0.5.0       tools_3.3.1       rgdal_1.2-3       grid_3.3.1        gtable_0.2.0     
[16] DBI_0.5-1         htmltools_0.3.5   lazyeval_0.2.0    assertthat_0.1    digest_0.6.10    
[21] tibble_1.2        purrr_0.2.2       ggplot2_2.2.0     tidyr_0.6.0       base64enc_0.1-3  
[26] htmlwidgets_0.8   scales_0.4.1      jsonlite_1.1
```

Comment: strange, I just updated both `raster` and `rgdal`, but this still does not work for me...

Comment: I added my sessionInfo. Maybe restart R so you have a clean environment.

Comment: Thanks for this. You prompted me to test this on my local machine where it did work with just the call to `raster`. No luck updating my packages or restarting R, but this definitely pushed me further. Will award the bounty as soon as I can.

Comment: I am still interested in why it does not work. What OS are you using on the machine that does not like this snippet?

Comment: sessionInfo pasted into thread.

Comment: Could you try `raster('n_tw-2013.e00', native = T)` on Debian? And maybe rename the file so it does not contain hyphen or an underscore. Just to be sure :)

Comment: same problem, `not recognised as a supported file format. Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
  Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131428/discussion-between-martin-schmelzer-and-colin).

Answer (score 5):

It appears you are dealing with an ArcInfo Exchange file - check this out [How To: Import an ArcInfo interchange file (E00) in ArcGIS](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000004705). Your trying to do this using R.

If you wanted to use a command-line approach to unpack e00 you could use [E00compr - A Library to Read/Write Compressed E00 Files](http://avce00.maptools.org/e00compr/) with is open source.

> Using the 'e00conv' Conversion Program
>
> 'e00conv' is a command-line executable that takes a E00 file as input (compressed or not) and copies it to a new file with the requested compression level (NONE, PARTIAL or FULL).
>
> e00conv   [NONE|PARTIAL|FULL]
>   input_file is the name of the E00 file to read from.
>   output_file is the name of the file to create. If the file already exists then it is overwritten.
>
> The last argument is optional and specifies the compression level to use when creating the output file (one of NONE, PARTIAL or FULL). The default is NONE (uncompressed).

If you had access to ArcGIS

The steps in ArcGIS:

[image]

> ArcGIS 10.x - All ArcGIS licenses

1. Open ArcMap.
2. Click the ArcToolbox icon. 
   ArcToolbox icon for ArcGIS 10.x
3. In ArcToolbox, expand Conversion Tools.
4. Expand 'To Coverage'.
5. Double-click 'Import from E00'.
6. In the 'Input interchange file' (E00 file) entry box, click Browse. Navigate to the desired directory and select the file. Name the output dataset.

Note:
File naming restrictions outlined at the beginning of this article still apply at ArcGIS 10.x.

7. Click OK. A dialog window appears and indicates the process has completed. Click Close.
8. Click 'Add Data' 
   [O-Image] ArcMap Add Data button for Desktop 10.x
   and navigate to the selected directory.

First convert the file to provide a compatible format for R, then try to reload the raster in R.

Comment: Gotcha. I don't have ArcGIS. Any way to do this at the command line or within R would be super valuable.

Comment: Possibly, I'll try to see what I can dig up. Do you have access to QGIS?

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide you with an alternative command-line option to conver the e00 file.

Comment: does it work with the file I have linked? Other approaches I have attempted to covert e00 files have returned empty directories.

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `readGDAL` from `library(rgdal)`

In your example should work:

```
n_tw_2013 <- readGDAL("path/to/the/file/n_tw-2013.e00")
```